# bigtable reverse timestamp advantage over regular timestamp

Tags: timestamp, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

[Bigtable docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#reverse_timestamps_only_when_necessary) say:

> By reversing the timestamp, you can design a row key where the most
> recent event appears at the start of the table instead of the end. As
> a result, you can get the N most recent events simply by retrieving
> the first N rows of the table.

My understanding is that assuming tables are sorted in ascending order then regular timestamp will mean recent events will be at the end of the table since those values increase whereas reverse timestamp will mean recent events will be at the beginning of the table since those values will decrease. My understanding is that this reverse timestamp design leverages sorting on the row key of the table.

Why is there a benefit for sorting ascending as opposed to descending - is the ascending sort the only type of sort supported in bigtable? Are "My understanding"s above correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding  is correct. The cloud Bigtable supports only lexicographically sorted keys. Therefore you can design a key by reversing the timestamp in order to get the N most recent events by retrieving the first N rows of the table.

> Storing time-series data in Cloud Bigtable is a natural fit. Cloud
> Bigtable stores data as unstructured columns in rows; each row has a
> row key, and row keys are **sorted lexicographically**
>
> Rows are sorted lexicographically by row key, from the lowest to the
> highest byte string. Row keys are sorted in big-endian byte order
> (sometimes called network byte order), the binary equivalent of
> alphabetical order.

[Time series and Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#time-series-cloud-bigtable)

[Designing your schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#row-keys)

For example this is how are lexicographically sorted (ascending) these values:

```
1425330757686
1425330757687
1425330757688
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there a benefit for sorting ascending as opposed to descending - is the ascending sort the only type of sort supported in bigtable?

Bigtable [stores data lexicographically](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#general-concepts:%7E:text=sorted%20lexicographically%20by%20row%20key) out of the box. This means that key "203" will be placed after "202", but key "00202" will be placed before "203". You can't sort data any other way.

Apart from that, your understandings are correct. When using reverse timestamp, recent events will be at the beginning of the table.